# Need to override a js file before pipeline execution

Tags: overriding, cypress, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a App.js file which has a line of code "if (preLoadSuccess && preLoadData?.Role !== 'NotAuthenticated')".

My need is to override '!==' to '===' when my cypress tests execute in pipeline.
Today I am manually updating this file to '===' before staring pipeline execution. I want to know if there is any way to override === when pipeline execution starts.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check the presence of Cypress property on `window`

```js
let condition = preLoadSuccess && preLoadData?.Role !== 'NotAuthenticated';  // non-test scenario
if (window.Cypress) {  // Cypress is running
 condition = preLoadSuccess && preLoadData?.Role === 'NotAuthenticated';  // test scenario
}
if (condition) {
  ...
```

or use an `env` parameter

```js
if (window.Cypress && window.Cypress.env('test-with-equality')) {
  ...
```